# Hash Password does not match while loading from DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, encryption, bcrypt

I'm trying to login with my credentials but while matching password after loading from db it returns always False if still password is correct.

Login Route-

```
router.post('/users/login', async (req, res) => {
    // console.log(req.body.email)
    // console.log(req.body.password)
    try {
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(req.body.email, req.body.password)
        res.send(user)
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e)
    }
})
```

Schema Pre-save

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {

    const user = this

    if (user.isModified('password') || user.isNew) {
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8)
    }

    next()
})
```

Login using credentials (email and password)-

```
userSchema.statics.findByCredentials = async (email, password) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    // console.log(user)
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login')
    }

    const hashedPwd = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
    console.log(hashedPwd)

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
    console.log('Password Match', isMatch)
    if (!isMatch) {
        throw new Error('Unable to login')
    }

    return user
}
```

Schema for User-

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', {
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        minLength: 7
    }
})
```

Password is stored in lowercase that's why it is showing false everytime i'm matching my password.

Comment: Every time you hash the password, it’ll be different due to random salts. That’s by design. That’s why you don’t hash the password again, but use the special comparison function to compare the plaintext password to the stored hash.

Answer (score 2):

While storing password in DB I stored it in lowercase letters so everytime while comparing user entered password from db password it results to False.

So, by removing `lowercase: true` from password of User schema my error got resolved.